# Snowflake issue when drop users

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

As Snowflake documentation,
I need ownership and rights to drop any object.

So someone created a user account using accountadmin role (owner of the account).
When I try to delete it or transfer ownership using owner role, I can't.

**Where am I wrong?**

> **USE ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN;**
>
> **DROP USER "xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.xxxx.xx";**
>
> *User '"xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.xxxx.xx" ' does not exist or not authorized.*

**If I perform some tests with the same account :**

> **USE ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN;**
>
> **CREATE USER "xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.xxxx.xx";**
>
> *User with login name 'xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.xxxx.xx' already exists.*

**If I try to create and delete users with this account...**

> **USE ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN;**
>
> **CREATE USER "yxxx.xxxx@xxxx.xxxx.xx";**
>
> *User yxxx.xxxx@xxxx.xxxx.xx successfully created.*
>
> **DROP USER "yxxx.xxxx@xxxx.xxxx.xx";**
>
> *yxxx.xxxx@xxxx.xxxx.xx successfully dropped.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to drop users after this command:

```
ALTER SESSION UNSET QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS_IGNORE_CASE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the ACCOUNTADMIN doesn't own the user.  I believe that only the owner can DROP.  Run:

```
SHOW USERS LIKE 'xxxx@xxxx.xx'
```

This will show you what role owns the user.  Use that role to drop the user.